# How to modify location of e2e tests in Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, cypress

I try to modify the Cypress test files location using the `cypress.json` config parameters but no luck so far.

```
{
  "testFiles": "e2e/specs/*.spec.js"
}
```

I get the following error message:

```sh
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files inside of this folder:

tests/e2e/specs
```

It seems like there is a base directory that I can't modify.

Answer (score 1):

try adding:

"integrationFolder": "e2e/specs"

in cypress.json